# Выполняется только первая строка

Tags: unity3d

пишу код для передвижения персонажа и возникла проблема

```
void Update()
    {
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = transform.forward * vertical * movementspeed;
        rb.velocity = transform.right * horizontal * movementspeed;
    }
```

работает только первый `rb.velocity` а второй нет
тоесть персонаж двигается только влево-вправо либо только вперед-назад
подскажите как решить пожайлуста

Comment: Может их сложить вместе эти векторы вертикальный и горизонтальный и тогда уже присвоить в `rb.velocity`?

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему немного переписав код

```
void Update()
    {
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Vector3 velocity = transform.rotation * new Vector3(horizontal * movementspeed, 0, vertical * movementspeed);
        rb.velocity = velocity;
    }
```